# image not showing in full (reactjs, css)

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to display an image that covers the whole screen, like a landing page for a website. But the only part of the image that shows is the one that stretches out because of more divs created.

react code looks like this

```
export default props =>
  <header className="masthead">
    <div className="container">
        <h1>Comapny Name</h1>
        <h2>Company motto</h2>
        <div className="container">
            <h1> hoiluuluu</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div><h1>hello</h1></div>
</header>
```

css:

```
header.masthead {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-image: url("./header-bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to provide screenshot of the current state?

Answer (score 0):

You can position your topmost element absolutely and pin it to all sides:

**Example ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1o65q0008l))**

```
header.masthead {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("./header-bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```